how do I make powerdns-recursor log its match to its RPZ?
I have powerdns-recursor on hundreds of machines set up with a rpz zone loaded from a distant server.
Everything works fine. The rpz contains only malware domain to avoid, so on most machines I need to log all the lookup resolution that match the rpz zone to trigger attention, but not the rest.
How may I achieve that ?
